# AWS Service Quotas info mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS Service Quotas. I check the table per region limit for dynamodb. It shows default 256 tables/region. However, the actual tables number is 271. Anyone please explain me why?

Info shown in service quota:

[image: info shown in service quota]

Actual value:

[image: actual value]

Comment: Do you actually have 271 tables or this may be some culprit  in the dynamodb console?

Comment: Is it causing you a problem? If you have a query about service quotas, you can contact AWS Customer Service (which is _not_ the same as AWS Support).

Comment: do you really have 271 table in a single project? first of all I suggest dynanodb is not so good for large project and 271 table for all stage then you can manage the different region according to stage so in one stage your table count will reduced

Comment: are you saying that the number can be wrong?